# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I try to upgrade my Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04.

1. Using the GUI Software Updater gives following information:

   > Software updates is no longer supported for Ubuntu 21.10
   > To increase security please install Ubuntu 21.04

   So, I follow instruction and click the Upgrade button!
   The GUI Software Updater just shuts down without response or information.
2. I tried the release upgrade as below.

   ```
   $ sudo do-release-upgrade
   [sudo] password for thomas:
   Looking for a new Ubuntu release
   Your Ubuntu release is no longer supported.
   For upgrade information you can visit:
   http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
   Install all available updates for your version before upgrading.*
   ```

   As far as I known I have installed all updates from Ubuntu, and the GUI Software &  Updates app is configured for daily information for updates.
   All previous version updates without problem.

So I kindly ask for your help in this issue to upgrade 21.04.

Comment: *Your Ubuntu release is no longer supported* says it all. The time for a normal online release upgrade is already gone. There is a way to do it (see next comment) but you have to ask yourself if it's worth the time, effort and risk when compared to (having backups and) doing a fresh **21.10** installation (21.04 will be EoL soon).

Comment: These types of upgrades can be dangerous, Thus are not recommend , Your ubuntu version 20.10 is no longer supported by canonical Thus cant be upgraded _safely_ , the method you _can_ try to do this upgrade is editing `sources.list` but this method can be dangerous!

Comment: Thanks for all the great tips and comments !!